# How to find magnetic moment without using the trick?

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, magnetic-moment

I'm trying to find the total magnetic moment of Manganese ion ($Mn^{2+}$), we could find the electronic configuration is $\rm [Ar]3d^5$. I think one way we could find the magnetic moment is to use the trick $\sqrt{n(n+2)}$ where $n$ is the number of unpaired electrons (which is 5 here). I'm not sure how this equation comes from, and is there a different method we could find that?

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly I found that from a youtube video, it only explained how to use the equation, but didn't say why it holds true.

Comment: Can you find this youtube video? It could be useful if you added a link to the video inside the question